# PHP IMAP : Get Distinct Sender

Tags: php, email, imap

Is there some means to only get the latest email from each sender during a set span of time?

Like algorithmically it's something like:

```
GET DISTINCT mails FROM inbox WHERE date BETWEEN this AND that
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Like algorithmically it's like `for m in message: seen[sender]=m; for s in seen: print seen[s]`

Comment: I don't think so, not via the protocol.  You'd have to download a list of all senders and compute it yourself.